# Running kafka consumer with Django

Tags: python, django, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've setup a `kafka` server on AWS and I already have a Django project acting as the producer, using `kafka-python`.

I've also setup a second Django project to act as the consumer (`kafka-python`), but I'm trying to figure out a way to run the consumer automatically after the server has started without having to trigger the consumer through an API call.

Everything I've tried so far either runs the consumer and blocks the server from starting or runs the server and blocks the consumer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's stopping you from putting the consumer as part of the server startup method rather than behind an API method?

Comment: That's one of the ways i've tried doing it. For example placing consumer in the main method in my manage.py file. If i place it at the start of the method, then the consumer runs but the server never starts since the consumer is basically an infinate loop. If i place it at the end of the method, the server starts but it never reaches the consumer part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this on a Django project : I put the consumer launch into a daemon thread into a method and I call this method in the manage.py file.

I'm not really sure about impacts of modify manage.py file, but it's work fine.

```
def run_consumers():
    thread = threading.Thread(name=my_consumer, target=main.lauch_consumer, args=()
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
```

And in manage.py I added :

```
if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN'):
    # Run consumers once at server start
    run_consumers()
```